# What is the C# 2.0 equivalent code of this lambda expression

Tags: lambda, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I need a functionality that enumerates through open explorer windows. And here is a code I've got:

```
delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(int processID)
{
    List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();

    foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processID).Threads)
    {                                //what is the magic going on beneath this?? :o
        EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (hWnd, lParam) => { handles.Add(hWnd); return true;}, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    return handles;
}
```

And the code continues here like this:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_MINIMIZED = 6;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (IntPtr handle in EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0].Id))
    {
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_MINIMIZED);
    }
}
```

My question is, in the first block of code, how do I replace the lambda expression so that I can compile the code using C# 2.0 in VS 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(int processID)
{
    List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();

    EnumThreadDelegate addWindowHandle = delegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr param)
    {
        handles.Add(hWnd); 
        return true;
    };

    foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processID).Threads)
    {
        EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, addWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    return handles;
}
```

Comment: That seems to be what exactly I'm looking for! I will get back soon

Answer (score 2):

Create a new method to pass into `EnumThreadWindows` like this:

```
static bool EnumThreadCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
{
    // Close the enumerated window.
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    return true;
}
```

And make a delegate to go along with it:

```
public delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate (IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
```

Then call the function like this:

```
foreach (ProcessThread pt in proc.Threads)
{
    EnumThreadWindows((uint)pt.Id, new EnumThreadDelegate(EnumThreadCallback), IntPtr.Zero); 
}
```

Source: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumThreadWindows.html